# Windows issue when using pm2 deploy

Tags: deployment, pm2

I have read several issues and ideas on how to work with `pm2` under a Windows machine, and believe it or not, my previous machine I had it working very well ... then I had to re.format it and completely forgot what I did before :(

and I've installed `pm2` after `npm` and with the command: `npm install pm2@latest -g`

for deploying and under the windows command line (`cmd`) I do:

- `pm2 deploy production`

but I always get:

```
--> Deploying to production environment
--> on host 10.200.73.136
Deploy failed
Deploy failed
```

if I use the git bash to run, I get weird git errors:

```
balex@DESKTOP-3LKNA7U  /d/Gavekortet/gogift-mainsite (master)
$ pm2 deploy production
--> Deploying to production environment
--> on host 10.200.73.136
      0 [main] sh 16020 C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\sh.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - fork: can't reserve memory for parent stack 0x600000 - 0x800000, (child has 0x400000 - 0x600000), Win32 error 487
    660 [main] sh 16020 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to sh.exe.stackdump
      0 [main] sh 13588 fork: child -1 - forked process 16020 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
sh: fork: retry: No child processes
1007561 [main] sh 8808 C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\sh.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - fork: can't reserve memory for parent stack 0x600000 - 0x800000, (child has 0x400000 - 0x600000), Win32 error 487
1008780 [main] sh 8808 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to sh.exe.stackdump
2266018 [main] sh 13588 fork: child -1 - forked process 8808 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
sh: fork: retry: No child processes
4274490 [main] sh 14924 C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\sh.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - fork: can't reserve memory for parent stack 0x600000 - 0x800000, (child has 0x400000 - 0x600000), Win32 error 487
4275199 [main] sh 14924 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to sh.exe.stackdump
5799995 [main] sh 13588 fork: child -1 - forked process 14924 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
sh: fork: retry: No child processes
9804559 [main] sh 6320 C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\sh.exe: *** fatal error in forked process - fork: can't reserve memory for parent stack 0x600000 - 0x800000, (child has 0x400000 - 0x600000), Win32 error 487
9804986 [main] sh 6320 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to sh.exe.stackdump
11142795 [main] sh 13588 fork: child -1 - forked process 6320 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0x100, errno 11
sh: fork: retry: No child processes
```

Any idea what am I missing (that I did before and can't remember exactly what) :(

P.S. same steps on my Mac machine, works flawlessly

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem today. Make sure that you have the latest version of pm2 (2.4.0 at the time of writing) and Git Bash.